# Class imported in the same package is not being recognized

Tags: java

I have these two java files: `Xls_Reader.java` and `WriteXMLFile.java` in the same directory called `filegeneration`. I am trying to use `Xls_Reader` class in `WriteXMLFile.java` so I did this

```
package fileGeneration;
import fileGeneration.Xls_Reader;
```

However I keep getting this error when trying to compile

```
WriteXMLFile.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
import fileGeneration.Xls_Reader;
  symbol:   class Xls_Reader
  location: class WriteXMLFile
WriteXMLFile.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
                        Xls_Reader xlsDataSheet = new Xls_Reader(dataSheetPath);
```

Why is Xls_Reader not being found?

Update: the following is in Xls_Reader

```
package fileGeneration;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;
//import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Xls_Reader {
```

Comment: Could you share the class declaration of Xls_Reader? One reason for this not to work might be that the package access is not possible (was it declared private?)

Comment: It is a bit long so I just edited my post.

Comment: If they are just a few files without a project (handled by maven or gradle) then you need to specify the classpath properly when running the compiler (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: If two classes are in the same package and one classes uses the other class, there's no need to import.

Comment: It is a project without Maven I am using different jar files....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to let the compiler knows about the classes to be compiled, you need to specify the classes explicitly. The compiler won't use the same folder to know that. You can read more about how ClassPath works here (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

An example of compiling multiple files from the command line here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-compile-multiple-files

I see that you are using another libraries like Apache POI, therefore it would be more convenient to use Maven or Gradle to handle both dependencies and deployments.